# What is the shortcut to Edit/Rename the Notepad++ tabs?

Tags: notepad++

While saving the file i need to rename it with shortcut keys but there is no shortcut key available for renaming the tab.

I tried manual way using mouse to rename the tab which works well but i need the shortcut key to edit or rename the notepad++ tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortcut defined for renaming the tabs but we can create our own key combination by following below steps.

1. Open Notepad++ Application.
2. Go to 'Settings'
3. Select 'Shortcut Mapper'
4. Select 'Rename'
5. Click on 'Modify'
6. Assign the shortcut ( Example: 'CTRL + E' )

Now when you press 'CTRL+E' Rename tab will appear.

Check the screenshot to follow the steps.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gjCBL_Wm9sq7KCDjY8eaM8jQIhG0q1LY